# How to to run a function every 12 hours inside a flask app?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have been creating an API that uses ML to predict some output, I need to update my dataset every 1 minute (fetch new data) and retrain the dataset every 12 hours, I am using multiprocessing to achieve this, and my app is deployed on a 4 GB dedicated server.

I am using an LSTM model and Nginx/gunicorn for the webserver for the flask app.

here's the code snippet on how I am calling those 2 functions:

```
def fetch():
    while True:
        #fetching done
        
        time.sleep(60) #runs every 60 minutes

def retrain():
    while True:
        #training of LSTM model

        time.sleep(43200) #runs every 12 hours

multiprocessing.Process(target=fetch).start()
multiprocessing.Process(target=retrain).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.Process(target=fetch).start()
    multiprocessing.Process(target=retrain).start()
    app.run(debug=False, host='0.0.0.0')
```

The problem I am facing is the CPU usage, I am getting up to 190% CPU usage, and the maximum length of my dataset is 100k, I am wondering there should be a better way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: I would use system's task manager for run it. On Linux I would use program `cron` to run script every 1 minut, and other script every 12 hours. And then script doesn't have to run all time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Celery` to run a task periodically, moving forward with `multiprocessing` will add complexity to your code. developing, maintaining and debugging would become thousand times harder.

take a look at the links below:

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html

https://rudra.dev/posts/setting-up-a-task-scheduler-in-flask